# have I coded this incorrectly?

Tags: c, gcc

I did some C programming couple decades ago.  I am trying to re-learn the language.  I wrote this.  I get something unexpected.  When I change the 'short int' to 'int', it seems to work.  Can anyone look at my code to see if anything is wrong with it or is this a compiler issue.  I am using gcc on Linux.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    short int age = 0;
    short int num_1_yr_olds = 0;
    short int num_2_and_3_yr_olds = 0;
    short int num_above_3_yr_olds = 0;

    while(1) {

        printf ("Enter age: ");
        scanf ("%d", &age);

        if (age < 1) {
            break;
        }

        switch (age) {
            case 1:
                ++num_1_yr_olds;
                break;
            case 2:
            case 3:
                ++num_2_and_3_yr_olds;
                break;
            default:
                ++num_above_3_yr_olds;
                break;
        }
    }
    printf ("Number of 1 year olds = %d\n", num_1_yr_olds);
    printf ("Number of 2 and 3  year olds = %d\n", num_2_and_3_yr_olds);
    printf ("Number above 3 year olds = %d\n", num_above_3_yr_olds);
}
```

Input

```
Enter age: 1
Enter age: 1
Enter age: 1
Enter age: -1
```

Output

```
Number of 1 year olds = -1
Number of 2 and 3  year olds = 0
Number above 3 year olds = 0
```

num_1_yr_olds value is getting messed up.  I expected a 3, I get a -1.  The value of num_1_yr_olds  becomes a -1 regardless of input.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
short int age = 0;
:
scanf ("%d", &age);
```

You really need to ensure that your data types match your format string. The correct format specifier for a `short int` is `%hd`, not `%d`.

Some compilers will actually check this and warn you.

What's likely to be happening is that the misalignment of data and format string is causing the `short int` to become the "wrong" value hence the counts are being screwed up.

---

In more depth, for a two's complement, little-endian architecture like x86, scanning an `int` into a `short` may put the least significant half into `age` and the most significant half into `num_1_year_olds` (if it's adjacent to `age` in memory).

Graphically, it may be clearer to think of it like this:

```
                         shorts in memory
                     +-----------------------+
What scanf("%hd") =< |          age          | \
  will write to.     +-----------------------+  = What scanf("%d")
                     |    num_1_year_olds    | /    will write to.
                     +-----------------------+
                     | num_2_and_3_year_olds |
                     +-----------------------+
                     | num_above_3_year_olds |
                     +-----------------------+
```

So, when you enter `1`, `age` becomes `1` and `num_1_year_olds` becomes `0`.

Each time you do that, it increases `num_1_year_olds` because `age` is `1` but that will be overwritten by the `scanf` the next time you get input.

When you finally enter `-1` (all 1 bits in two's complement), `age` becomes `-1` and so does `num_1_year_olds`.

Then, because `age` is less than one, the loop breaks, and the values are what you see: `{-1, 0, 0}`.

Comment: That certainly worked.  I did realize it was memory issue, however not sure what caused it.  Has the %hd always been part of C?

Comment: @rpat: well, at least back to c89. It's even in my 2nd ed K&R (the ANSI one). Before that, well, I threw out those books a _long_ time ago.

Comment: Thank for sharing your wisdom.  I have a K&R dating back to 88.  I guess need to get rid of that.  Can you recommend a book?

Comment: @rpat, the book I use is the ISO standard, but that's because I know the simpler stuff, it's only the dark corners of the language I'd be looking up, and I've found the standard better for that stuff. I wouldn't recommend it to a beginner unless they were a serious masochist :-)

Comment: Having said that, I have an early edition of ABC at home which I remember being useful. See http://www.amazon.com/Book-Programming-4th-Edition/dp/0201183994 if you want to check it out.

Comment: @rpat Your K&R from 1988 is K&R 2nd edition; don't get rid of it, read it cover to cover.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
scanf ("%hd", &age);
```

Since age is of type short int.